# how importing pdf files in swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I am beginner iOS developer and i  have [this book](http://www.apress.com/9781484204108?gtmf=b).
Its greater book but I did not find my answer on it.
I am try and search as many as I can about how I can importing pdf file in xcode6.1 using swift.
The idea is my app for learn some English lessons for beginner level so i put all lessons in  separated pdf files and i want user click on lesson names  then pdf file according to this lesson will open.

I hope you understand idea.
please help me how I can do this

Comment: Please show what you have done so far and where you get stuck. We are also busy developers. If you show your current code and where you need help, there is a bigger chance you will get help.

Comment: i dont know how to start i need just a start point to go:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. if you want to use the PDF-File from the network, you can download this file in your application that you can use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is one of the easiest ways. The request should look like this

   ```
   var configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
   var man = AFURLSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: configuration)

   var URL = NSURL(string: "http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf")
   var request = NSURLRequest(URL:URL!)

   var downloadTask = man.downloadTaskWithRequest(request, progress: nil,
   destination:{(targetPath:NSURL!,response:NSURLResponse!) -> NSURL! in
   let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
   let outPath = String(format: "%@/download/", documentsPath)
   var url:NSURL! = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outPath)
   return url.URLByAppendingPathComponent(response.suggestedFilename as String!)
   },
   completionHandler:{(response:NSURLResponse!,filePath:NSURL!,error:NSError!)  in
       println(response.suggestedFilename)
   })

   downloadTask.resume();
   ```
2. If you want to display PDF without downloading, you can use the UIWebView

   ```
   let url : NSURL! = NSURL(string: "http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf")
           webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
   ```
3. if you want to use local pdf files you need to download them to your project and then used with this code

   ```
   var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PdfFile", ofType:"pdf")
   var data     = NSData(contentsOfFile:filePath)
   ```

Comment: yes, that what i want i will learn how to use it. thank you .